# Techniques for anomaly detection across different time series?

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, anomaly-detection

Most anomaly detection techniques/packages focus on anomaly detection within a single time series; ie, take some sort of steady-state average and alert if the data suddenly goes above or below some threshold. My problem is totally different, however.

I have a hardware device that performs the same operation repeatedly. Most of the time it succeeds, but sometimes it fails. I have sensors that measure position and angle (6DOF), and I have a large data set of each attempt, whether or not it was a success or failure, and the sensor data (and first and second derivatives) from a few seconds before the event to a few seconds after.
What I'm looking for is a technique or python package that can analyze all this time series data and, given label of Success or Failure, identify if there are any anomalies that typically lead to a failure.

I've done quite a bit of Googling and Stack Overflowing, but keep coming up with "typical" anomaly detection packages. Maybe I'm using the wrong keywords or language here to describe what I'm looking for? Any suggestions or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have sufficient amounts of labeled data (some 1000x) data-points, then this might probably better handled as a classification problem - not (unsupervised) anomaly detection.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a machine learning solution if I understand correctly:

- You've got lots of sets of time series data
- Each set is tagged as success or failure
- you want to identify the properties/patterns of the time series that lead to failure

There won't techniques/packages that will work out-of-the-box for you because of your unique data set so a more custom solution will be required.